Mounting an NTFS partition at boot and without password
I have a dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows laptop in which the Windows NTFS partition is shared with Linux.  At the moment the mounting arrangement for this NTFS partition is such that it is not mounted through fstab, only with User Session Defaults enabled under gnome-disks.
I would like it to mount at boot (because I have an application [Visual Studio Code] which will remember where it was if the previously-opened directory is still there), so I disabled User Session Defaults in gnome-disks in order that the Mount at system startup box is ticked.  Now the partition has an fstab entry.
However, this hasn't helped the use-case as now I have to enter my admin password before access to the mounted NTFS partition is permitted, it still isn't "already there" as far as Visual Studio Code is concerned.
I have read various posts about chown/chmod being the way to resolve this but I am paranoid that I will mess-up the file permissions on the NTFS partition if I put a step wrong (been there before): can anyone guide me as to how to achieve my aim, i.e. have the NTFS partition mounted and authenticated by the time I am logged into Ubuntu, no additional keys to press to make it happen?
